# Creating a system account used by a module: Is setting the password with drupal_random_bytes() too excessive, or is there a better method?

Tags: users

I am planning to create a module that would use a system account similar to the [Community user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/-1) seen on Stack Exchange sites. As the system account would have permissions that normal users don't have, I would like to avoid somebody logs in with that account, and get permissions that a site maintainer would have.

Is using [drupal_random_bytes()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_random_bytes/7) to create a password a good method, or is it too excessive, and I should use a different method? In any case, I was thinking of periodically changing the password; I guess this means I could use a faster way to generate the password, as long as the password is still random, and with at least X characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use [`user_password()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_password/7) to get the password string. When Drupal hashes it, for example during [`user_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7), with [`user_hash_password()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7), [`drupal_random_bytes()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_random_bytes/7.x) is used as part of the [`_password_generate_salt()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/_password_generate_salt/7) calculation.

You may also be interested in preventing login through the UI by that account with validation handler added to the login form.

Comment: `user_password()` is still defined in Drupal 8.x and Drupal 9.x, contrary to `drupal_random_bytes()`. That is another reason to use it.